# Add Open Graph meta data to hook with insights from Facebook sharer.php

Tags: feature-request, promotion, statistics

Please entertain the possibility of adding OG metadata to the pages if you are going to use Facebook sharing buttons.

You could assign the owner to the Stack Exchange Facebook page or open an *official* Web Applications page to monitor social engagement.

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="YOUR_PAGE_ID" />
```

> Facebook Insights for Domains offers a consolidated view of key metrics for any website, even those that have not implemented Facebook Platform. For example, if a user links to your site in their Facebook status message, that data is included in the analytics for your domain. You can access sharing metrics and demographic information per domain and per URL so you can optimize your content for sharing and better tailor your content to your audience.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

I mean you can even hook it back into /admin/analytics and pull the data in there.

Reasoning?

You gave us the /analytics tool for a reason right? This would better help that reason. There is a current trend occurring over the last two months on Web Applications and I don't know whether it is a result of the Stack Exchange promotion Team, SEO, more presence or all of the above.

[image: Two month data for visits]

With new data such as social insights a moderator or a team of community volunteers involved in a promotion can better formulate proposals and do post event analysis.

We are a site of hit and run so who ever is sharing links on Twitter, Facebook and Google Minus we want them. Because? We like them and we need to figure out how to get more of them. Because? We would like a community, not hit and runs only.