# How to get attention to unanswered no-status feature request questions?

Tags: support, meta, unanswered-questions

Today this [search](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A0%20locked%3Ano%20-%5Bstatus-*%5D%20answers%3A0%20%5Bfeature-request%5D) returns four [feature-requests](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-requests) that have no status tag and no answers :

(sorted by number of votes)

10 upvotes 2 downvotes 4 comments
[Drop spam flag lock action limit from 6 flags to 4](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2450/88163)

10 upvotes 0 downvotes 3 comments
[Enable tagged syntax highlighting](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2421/88163)

8 upvotes 0 downvotes 0 comments
[Clarify "Ask Question" placeholder text](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4140/88163)

4 upvotes 0 downvotes 0 comments
[Add Open Graph meta data to hook with insights from Facebook sharer.php](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1109/88163)

Since we cannot offer bounties on meta posts, how could we get proper (Community Managers, developers, someone else?) attention to those questions?

Some (weird?) ideas:

- [Bumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Bumping)

  - by doing a relevant edit
  - by doing an irrelevant edit
  - by posting a "Me too" answer
- Making a post on Meta SE
- Promoting those posts on Twitter, Facebook, some other online place?
- Organizing a meet up?